# Connecting google cloud ml-engine to google cloud sql

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I am trying access data on a `google cloud SQL database` as inputs in a `google ml-engine` training script.

**Question:** Is there a good way to do this securely?

Currently I can access by allowing all `IP's` access on `SQL server`, and relying only on `database passwords` for security.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use the cloud SQL proxy:

https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql

(I haven't tried it)

Comment: I ended up using this solution, but with a custom service account defined via the `--config` argument to gain access